# Install mysql 8.0 on Debian 12

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, mysql

I'm starting with a new installation.

1. sudo wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.29-1_all.deb
2. sudo apt install ./mysql-apt-config_*_all.deb
3. sudo apt update
4. sudo apt install mysql-server

And at the end of install, i have this error :

```
Setting up mysql-community-client (8.0.36-1debian12) ...
Setting up mysql-client (8.0.36-1debian12) ...
Setting up mysql-community-server (8.0.36-1debian12) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
installed mysql-community-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 8.0.36-1debian12); however:
Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.11.2-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.36-9+deb12u4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-community-server
mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried that on 2 different servers and i have the same error.

I didn't have this error a few months ago with the same steps.

Comment: try out: `apt --force-yes install mysql-community-server` then `dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Thank you :) i have this message  dpkg --configure -a :
Setting up mysql-community-server (8.0.36-1debian12) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service → /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service.
Could not execute systemctl:  at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-invoke line 145.
Could not execute systemctl:  at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-invoke line 145. And it doesn't works.

Comment: @gaetan did you forget to issue the `systemctl` command with `sudo`?

Comment: I'm in root :). and it worked before.

Answer (score 0):

You never want to `--force` a package install of any package in any Package Manager as this usually just leads to more breakages/issues later.

### Properly Install MySQL

1. `sudo apt remove mysql-server` - Uninstall what's been *forced*
2. `sudo apt update` - Make sure we're starting wit the most up-to-date repository changes
3. Already done:

   - `sudo wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.26-1_all.deb`
4. `sudo apt install ./mysql-apt-config_*_all.deb` - Start the installer you just downloaded(which you have done):

   - Choose: MySQL Server and Cluster
   - Version 8.0
   - Highlight OK, Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. `sudo apt install mysql-server` <-- Did you alter this command with the `-y` option?

Stopping here for a moment: The package `mysql-server` is an alias to the Community Edition as seen in:
[image: MySQL Apt Install].

Note that you must use the alias `mysql-server` to pull in all the dependencies, one of which is the Community Server.  I can't tell if a dependency is missing from the OP's partially posted apt run, or if he added the `-y` option.

To the OP: Did you see the `my.cnf` configuration screens during the attempt you posted? See [Terminal photos in Step 3](https://www.linuxbuzz.com/how-to-install-mysql-on-debian-12/).  The root database password, and the encryption method must be set before the `--configure` step can complete.  If you added the `-y` option, this would write `my.cnf` with no root password/no encryption, which would cause the configure phase to fail.

Comment: Yes i saw the my.cnf and I fill in the password and other settings and i have to put yes otherwise the installer will abort. 
I have the same error, and i can't use version 8.0.26 with debian 12 the minimum viable version is 8.0.29.
Every time i have the same error...

Comment: I make the procedure work manually before automating it.

Comment: Look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389747/error-processing-package-mysql-community-server-during-apt-get-upgrade).  Try gracious's answer and Deathgrips answer

Comment: I have tried many solutions but it doesn't works too :/ i have tried the installation of mariadb it works fine....

Comment: Is systemd installed properly?

Comment: Can you fix it [manually](https://askubuntu.com/a/1504395/267913)?

Comment: No it doesn't work even manually
Systemd work properly because mariadb works.